# Program for XML edition

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I need to create a program that makes XML editing possible in user-friendly way. I tried to find some controls for that and there's nothing interesting, Only TreeView, Does anyone know any interesting one? Or maybe someone knows easy ways to solve my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on your use cases. We use [XML Spy](http://www.altova.com/de/produkte/xmlspy/xml_editor.html) (http://www.altova.com/de/produkte/xmlspy/xml_editor.html)